# Generate MXD layer info report

Tags: arcpy, mxd, reports

I'd like to generate a report about MXD layers for a handful of MXDs. I want the report to display their name, workspace path and scale range settings.

I can get the first two with ArcPy but I didn't find a way to get the scale ranges. Can this be done with ArcPy? Or perhaps there's some other way to generate the type of report I'm looking for?

I found this but it doesn't give me scale range info: http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=A910AB18-1422-2418-3418-3885D388EF60

Here's the code I've started with:

```
import os, arcpy

directory = r"D:\MapTemplates\Map_Templates"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for myFile in files:
            fileExt = os.path.splitext(myFile)[1]
            if (fileExt == ".mxd"):
                fullPath = os.path.join(root, myFile)
                print myFile

                myMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
                layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(myMap)
                for layer in layers:
                    wsPath = ""
                    try:
                        wsPath = layer.workspacePath
                    except:
                        pass
                    if wsPath:
                        print "    " + layer.name + " : " + wsPath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do this at 10.0 but in the [What's New at 10.1 PDF](http://resourcesbeta.arcgis.com/en/help/pdf/whats_new_in_arcgis.pdf) (which is available via [resources.esri.com](http://resources.esri.com)) two new properties on the Layer class of arcpy.mapping are described:

▪ maxScale—Provides the ability to set or get the layer's maximum scale threshold.

▪ minScale—Provides the ability to set or get the layer's minimum scale threshold.

Comment: Looks like ESRI is slowly getting there... Thanks for the link :-)